# Is this a special or ordinary use of "think"?

Tags: imperatives, mood

There is a particular use of the word “think” that I’m familiar with (imperative mood I would say), but unable to find any reference work mentioning it. It’s used when one is suggesting someone might gain a good understanding of an individual or an issue by imagining it in a particular manner, often unusual or humorous. For example: “She was as unsuited to the job as could be imagined – think Emily Post as a rugby coach.” Has anyone seen a special reference to this usage…or have I wasted your time and answered my own question: that it is simply an imperative use of the word “think”?

Comment: It sounds like thinking about it helped; go ahead and write an answer with your research from a source; it's encouraged!  Welcome to EL&U SE.

Comment: There aren’t any particularly satisfying answers here, but it’s a start: ["Think (noun)" in phrases meaning "Think of (noun)"/ "Like (noun)"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297217/think-noun-in-phrases-meaning-think-of-noun-like-noun)

Comment: The usage became popular, I believe, with 'Think bike !' an exhortation to drivers to be careful of cyclists in their blind spot.

Comment: @NigelJ That's not the same. "bike" is not a metaphor for bicyclists.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be closest to definition 5c from the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200799?rskey=1FMpLC&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> transitive. With simple object, referring to something real: to form a definite conception of by a conscious mental act; to picture in one's mind, apprehend clearly (with or without direct perception).
>
> 2003   I. Ryder in N. *Ind Beyond Branding* ix. 152   The last few years have seen a significant shift in the way marketing inside technology companies has developed brand positioning and messages (think Orange, think Sony, think Intel).

It's not quite the same because it's listing real examples to consider, not a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a fairly recent usage, and as such might be considered 'special'.

But it's listed (in the base form) without a 'slang' or 'colloquial' caveat by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think):

> **think** [verb] [transitive]
>
> 8a: to center one's thoughts on
>
> - *talks and thinks business*
>
> 8b: to form a mental picture of

and by [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/think):

> **think** [verb] [transitive]
>
> 7: To concentrate one's thoughts on; keep as a point of focus:
>
> - *Think victory.*

It is also listed by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/think), but only in those senses labelled 'American English':

> **think** [verb] [transitive]
>
> 7:  to have the mind turned steadily toward; have constantly in mind
>
> - *think success*

The 'Think N' format is widely known and used in the UK, but it *might* still be considered 'conversational / informal' by some here.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure those definitions match this use. In the OP's example, "think X" means that X is a metaphor for the thing being described.

Comment: Yes, it's a broadening. Obviously, 'form a mental picture of' goes beyond the literal. It would be nice to find a dictionary adding 'consider [NP]/[NP as a NP] [as an example / a parallel]' as a sense. And OED does get close.